# How to achieve Multiple Inheritance by registering different Types using GObject?

Tags: inheritance, gobject

I would like to know how to achieve Multiple Inheritance using GObject.  For example i have two classes A and B.  I have another class named C.  Now i want to make **C derived from A as well B.** This has to be done using **GObject in C**.  I have written the basic code and its working.  But I dunno **how to register multiple types(TYPE_A and TYPE_B**) in the derived class.
   Your help will be really very helpful for me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

GObject (thankfully) does *not* support multiple inheritance.

You can get pretty close by [using an interface](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gtype-non-instantiable-classed.html).  Interfaces in GObject are a bit like mix-ins--they can have methods with or without implementations and properties.  They don't have their own storage, though, so if you *really* need a field your only option is using something like [g_object_set_qdata_full](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#g-object-set-qdata-full).  Technically that will be exposed, but if the name is properly prefixed it is pretty clear that it is meant to be private and people will stay out of it.

Comment: The class that implements the interface should implement any private storage that its implementation of the interface requires e.g. storing the values of properties.

Comment: Ideally, yes.  The qdata hack is only for when that isn't feasible--like if you don't really want the properties to be part of the API.  Using qdata is much less visible than a public property, and you can name it in a way which makes it clear that it is meant to be private.